# RAILS version not consistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

see this commands :

```
run@vm:/CARGO/rails_6.1/cargo_beta/cargo$ rails -v
Rails 6.1.0
run@vm:/CARGO/rails_6.1/cargo_beta/cargo$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 20535
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.1)
irb(main):001:0>
```

So why the rails console still using the version before the upgrade - 6.0.3 1 ?

Comment: have you tried stopping `spring` (`bin/spring stop`) and then running `rails c` again?

Comment: yes - that helps ! - thnak you ;-)